# CSS/JS: mimic background-image cover using image element with known width and height

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to create letterboxes for video thumbnails in css. Thumbnails can be any size but I want them to fit within a box with a fixed aspect ratio of 16:9. This is easy to accomplish if I use the `background-image` properties. See the example below:

```css
.container {
   background-color: gray;
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   padding-top: 56.25%;
   background-size: contain;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: center;
}

.container1 {
   background-image: url("https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/640x480.png");
}

.container2 {
   background-image: url("https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/720x240.png");
}
```

```html
<div class="container container1">
</div>
<br/>
<div class="container container2">
</div>
```

However, using `background-image` introduces a few problems. I only want the background of `.container` to be `gray` while the thumbnail is loading, once it has loaded I want it to be `black`. I also want to replace the thumbnail url with a default thumbnail url if for some reason the thumbnail fails to load. I cannot think of a way to do this without being able to use the `onload` and `onerror` events of an actual image element.

Fortunately, since in my actual code I am fetching the thumbnail urls dynamically I can also return the width and height of a thumbnail so I know it before I try to load it. However, I cannot figure out how to convert the width and height of the thumbnail into the correct percent it needs to be to cover the center of the box the same way the first example does using `background-image`. See the example below:

```js
let c1ThumbnailWidth = 640;
let c1ThumbnailHeight = 480;
let c2ThumbnailWidth = 720;
let c2ThumbnailHeight = 240;

$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.container1 img').css('left', 100 * (1 - (9 / 16) * (c1ThumbnailWidth / c1ThumbnailHeight)) / 2 + '%');
  $('.container2 img').css('left', 100 * (1 - (9 / 16) * (c2ThumbnailWidth / c2ThumbnailHeight)) / 2 + '%');

  $('.container img').one('load', function() {
    $(this).parent().css('background-color', '#000');
  });
  
  $('.container img').on('error', function () {
    $(this).attr('src', 'default.jpg');
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
   background-color: gray;
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   padding-top: 56.25%;
}

.container img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container container1">
    <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/640x480.png">
</div>
<br/>
<div class="container container2">
    <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/720x240.png">
</div>
```

How can I make the image element mimic the behavior of a `background-image` set to `cover` or alternatively how can I tell when a `background-image` has loaded or failed to load and adjust it accordingly?

Comment: Check this line: `$('.container img').one('load', function() {` - should that be `on`?

Comment: Alternate trick 1: use img to load the picture, but make it invisible. When it has loaded, that means it's in the cache now. Update the background color/image. Alternate trick 2: download the picture via ajax and convert to a data uri on the client side. Then update background color/image with the data uri.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using CSS object-fit on the image element?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit